# Overlaying data's density histogram with dlnorm in R, ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, statistics, statsmodels

I'm using Canada's census data with variables Wage on the x-axis and the density on the y-axis. I'm trying to overlay the graph I've created with the log-normal distribution `dlnorm` but I'm not sure what to use as the meanlog and sdlog parameter values. I've tried using `mean(data$Wages)` and `sd(data$Wages)`, as well as taking the natural logarithm of both, etc. Nothing gives me a graph remotely similar to the density histogram I have generated.

Is this because my data is not log-normal? How can I find the correct meanlog and sdlog parameters?

This is my code:

```
inc_plot <- data_adults %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=Wages)) +
  geom_histogram(aes(y=..density..),  bins=100,fill="transparent", colour="black")+
  scale_x_continuous(labels=scales::comma) +
  stat_function(fun = dlnorm,
      args = list(meanlog = 48637.91, sdlog = 62459.15),
      col = "red")

inc_plot
```

The current parameters are by using the aforementioned `mean()` and `sd()` functions.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you set `meanlog = mean(log(your_data))` and likewise `sdlog = sd(log(your_data))` the density should approach the histogram.

```r
library(ggplot2)


df <- data.frame(x = rlnorm(1e4))

ggplot(df, aes(x)) +
  geom_histogram(
    aes(y = after_stat(density)),
    bins = 100, fill = "transparent", colour = "black"
  ) +
  stat_function(
    fun = dlnorm,
    args = list(meanlog = mean(log(df$x)), sdlog = sd(log(df$x))),
    colour = "red"
  )
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-08-23 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

An alternative would be to use `ggh4x::stat_theodensity(distri = "lnorm", colour = "red")`. (disclaimer: I'm the author of ggh4x)

Comment: You're right, it worked! I'm not sure why calculating out the constants by hand and inputting them didn't work. Thank you so much!